# finding simple rectangles in image, save and replace them

Tags: python, image, image-processing

How could I find simple rectangles in image such as:
[image]

save them in separate picture files and replace them by a simple description such as:
[image]

Comment: Do you assume that the first image is an RGB image?

Comment: Are the rectangles in a constant color known beforehand ?

Comment: Yes. @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 1):

Turn the image to binary by assigning white where you see the color of a rectangle and black elsewhere.

Detect the connected components and determine their bounding box.

Now you can replace the content of the image in these bounding boxes.

Repeat for every rectangle color.

---

There must be a rule to tell which text to write in which box. But you did not state that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an RGB image.
One possible solution would be to use [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html) or [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to convert the image into an array (3 channels). Then set a threshold for the colours.
For example, the red colour is RBG=(255,0,0). You could set a threshold of more than 200 for the first channel and less than 5 for the second and third channels.
Then you determine the coordinates of the localised area and get the resulting array.
Then, you convert this array to white. So, replace this array with a new array (having the same dimension) with the white colour RGB=rgb(255,255,255).
Since you already know the position of the localised rectangle, you can [label the new image with PIL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adding-text-on-image-using-python-pil/), for example.